# how to ask general question

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I ask a question in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487030/is-there-bookmark-in-geany) after reading answer I tell my self: "...That was a good plugin for Geany which make my work so easier! may be there are sort of another great plugins for Geany which make developers work so easier. But the point is, I do not know what I am looking for". You know the story is like this when you ask your friend "Can you suggest me some useful plugins for Geany. It is so important that your friend never tell you Hay body this an OFF QUESTION!!" so I am sure this kind of questions are general and depends on the work and also SO's policy is great and respectable[Thanks to all wonderful members]. But How we can ask general questions. OR better to say .Can I put this question on the stack:"what useful plugins you suggest for the geany"

Comment: I havent used this site myself - maybe a good match? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @fossfreedom I doubt in it's current form as good candidate for SR.

Comment: For general questions that are looking for opinions and not a direct answer to a specific question this site is not the best place to ask them.  But you can always ask on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can you suggest me some useful plugins for Geany?

The problem with your question is that there isn't a way that I could got it wrong. Is not that there are several ways to do the stuff you want, but you don't put some specifics restrictions that people have to follow. Is like: give me a list of X. It just don't work.

> **Questions that lack any specificity at all.** Now we're in a situation where there are *multiple "correct" answers* because there are *no criteria for proving anything incorrect*! Questions asking for OpenGL tutorials or help designing systems for which no requirements are provided fall into this category, and often become not just too broad but overly opinion-based.

The same happens with everything else you ask:

> what useful plugins you suggest for the geany

*Suggest me a good X?*: Opinion based.

---

What you can do is ask for something with some requirements that made it special:

> I'm looking for a Geany pluging that do awesomesauce, while fooring the bar. It should work in Windows, Mac and Linux, because I travel a lot. Should work with Geany version X.Y and up.

The same applies for [Software Recommendation](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/226) and make sure to read their help page. They are way more strict with quality and formatting:

> I'm looking for a Geany plugin with the following characteristics:
>
> - Should be awesomesauce
> - Should foo the bar
> - Must work in all operative systems
> - Should work with Geany version X.Y and up.